# Scheduler Error in TYPO3 8.7.2

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm trying to setup a cronjob for the scheduler but getting errors for non existing DB tables.

Via cli_dispatch.phpsh

```
/usr/local/bin/php_cli /home/www/MyAccount/html/typo3/typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler

Oops, an error occurred: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT `content` FROM `cf_cache_hash` WHERE (`identifier` = ?) AND (`expires` >= ?)' with params ["22b1624a39d90c5db056873686cabf4f", 1498474993]:

Table 'usr_MyAccount_1.cf_cache_hash' doesn't exist
```

Via Symfony Command

```
/usr/local/bin/php_cli /home/www/MyAccount/html/typo3/typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 scheduler:run

Uncaught TYPO3 Exception An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT `content` FROM `cf_extbase_object` WHERE (`identifier` = ?) AND (`expires` >= ?)' with params ["3bcc835c5d8d7866a0ce2dc41464b9a8", 1498475122]:

Table 'usr_MyAccount_1.cf_extbase_object' doesn't exist
thrown in file /html/typo3/typo3_src-8.7.2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php
in line 53
```

The "Database analyzer" says everything is OK. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the APCu Cache. Since APCu doesn't work with CLI you have to disable it for CLI commands. Until now there isn't a good solution for that problem. See: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/78140